# UI Event Flow class

Tags: javascript, event-handling, callback

**Purpose:**

> I wanted a way to improve event clarity and event code organization. I
>   observed that every single event flow went through the following
>   steps:
>
> - Trigger -> UI Change -> (Async) Action -> UI Change

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Angryr/86oecufq/).

**Notes & Concerns**

- Something about the name of the class seems bad, but I can't come up with something better.
- Are there ways to make the usage more clear to someone who didn't write the class?
- Is there a way to make it where the user doesn't have to call the `callback` function in `preAction` and `action` and not have them fire before the user's function has completed?

**Class Definition: UIEvent**

```
// PURPOSE: 
//  I wanted a way to improve event clarity and event code organization.
//  I observed that every single event flow went through the following steps:
//      Trigger -> UI Change -> (Async) Action -> UI Change
// EXAMPLES:
//  Add button Click -> Disable add button -> Add new row -> Enable add button
//  Save button click -> Disable save button -> Save row -> Replace row
//  Edit button click -> Change button visibility -> Enable Controls -> Do Nothing.
// PARAMETERS:
//  This function takes an object of settings with the following fields.
//  'eventElement': 
//      A function for selecting the element that will trigger the event from the container element provided to the Initialize() function.
//      e.g. (container) => container.querySelector(".some-class")
//  'eventType':
//      The event triggered by the element above.
//      e.g. "click", "change", etc.
//  'preAction': 
//      A function that is fired when the event in triggered.
//      Has the parameters (e, callback) where e is the eventArgs from the original event and callback is the function to be called when this function has completed.
//      Remember to call the 'callback' when done or the 'action' and 'postAction' won't be called.
//  'action': 
//      A function that is fired after the preAction has completed.
//      Has the parameters (e, callback) where e is the eventArgs from the original event and callback is the function to be called when this function has completed.
//      Remember to call the 'callback' when done or the 'postAction' won't be called.
//  'postAction': 
//      A function that is fired after the action has completed.
//      Has the parameter (e) which is the eventArgs of the original event.
// INITIALIZTION:
//  The Initialize(container) function sets up the event listener on the 'eventElement' given a container.
//  If no container is provided, it will default to document.
function UIEvent(settings) {

    var thisUIEvent = this;

    this.GetElement = (container) => settings.eventElement(container);
    this.EventType = settings.eventType;

    // Executed before the 'Action'.
    // If you provide your own event handler you must call the 'callback' function when done.
    this.PreAction = function (e) {

        if (settings.preAction) {
            settings.preAction(e, thisUIEvent.Action)
        } else {
            thisUIEvent.Action(e);
        }

    };

    // Executed after the 'PreAction'.
    // If you provide your own event handler you must call the 'callback' function when done.
    this.Action = function (e) {

        if (settings.action) {
            settings.action(e, thisUIEvent.PostAction);
        } else {
            thisUIEvent.PostAction(e);
        }

    };

    // Executed after the 'Action'.
    this.PostAction = function (e) {

        if (settings.postAction) {
            settings.postAction(e);
        }

    };

    // Must be called to create the event listener.
    this.Initialize = (container) => {

        var element = thisUIEvent.GetElement(container || document);
        if (element === null) { return; }

        element.addEventListener(thisUIEvent.EventType, function (e) {
            thisUIEvent.PreAction(e);
        });

    };

}
```

**Example Usage: Add Row Button**

```
var AddRowEvent = new UIEvent({
    eventType: "click",
    eventElement: (container) => container.querySelector(".add-new-row"),
    preAction: (e, callback) => {
        document.querySelector(".add-new-row").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        if (callback) {
            callback(e);
        }
    },
    action: (e, callback) => {

        var defaultOrder = { Messages: [{ Text: "This is a new row", Color: "green" }, { Text: "This is a new row", Color: "green" }], DeliveryDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString() };

        var newRowHtml = Render.Once("row-template", defaultOrder);
        var row = Grid.InsertRowBeforeIndex(advanceOrdersTableSelector, newRowHtml);
        initializeRow(row);
        toggleCanEditRow(row, true);

        if (callback) {
            callback(e);
        }

    },
    postAction: (e) => {
        document.querySelector(".add-new-row").removeAttribute("disabled")
    }
});
AddRowEvent.Initialize(); // Same as AddRowEvent.Initialize(document) thanks to defaults.
```